# What on-going maintenance do I need to do for a reference repo that uses git lfs?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have setup a git **reference repo** on our jenkins server using `--mirror` (we only have one remote).  Documentation I have read indicates that I will periodically  need to run `git fetch --all` in the reference repo and I have setup a maintenance job to do that.

However, in order to populate the `lfs` directory in the reference repo (because the initial clone did not do this) I initally needed to do `git lfs fetch --all`.  My instinct was to add this command to the maintenance job, but it appears that it performs more work than necessary (I'm seeing a lot of output regarding the number of found objects) and I am wondering if I should be using `--recent` or perhaps just plain-ole `git lfs fetch`?

Using git 2.15.1.windows.2; lfs version 2.3.4;